# How to get "Error Message" from shim.Error("Error Message") from query request in NodeSDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In `fabcar` sample i modified the query request from `query.js` as follow:

```
const request = {
        chaincodeId: 'fabcar',
        fcn: 'queryCarss',
        args: []
    };
    return channel.queryByChaincode(request);
```

Now when i execute `query.js`, i get blank response. But it should be returning an error saying "Invalid Smart Contract function name.", as chaincode returns

```
return shim.Error("Invalid Smart Contract function name.")
```

How can we get error message returned via shim.Error(".."), after query request from node SDK.

Answer (score 0):

in your sendTransactionProposal, you will be returned with and array of 2 results (ProposalResponses and Proposal).
Your error will be contained in the ProposalResponses.

Note that Proposal Responses will contain the responses from all the endorsing peers that you have sent to.

Assuming that all of them return the same response (they should) you will only have to select the first response. (eg. proposalresponse[0])